# Create SiteCollection from a SiteTemplate that exists in another SiteCollection?

Tags: sharepoint-server

As I've asked in the title, I have a `SiteCollectionA` which contains `SiteTemplateA`.
Now I want to create a `SiteCollectionB` from `SiteTemplateA`.

Can I do that by `C#` code, or `Powershell`, or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the new Site Collection without selecting a Template by choosing `Select Template Later` option.

Once the new site collection is ready. Navigate to the Site Collection this will prompt you to select the template. Here you have option to upload custom template and use it.

You can automate this using below PowerShell scripts

```
New-SPSite http://newsitecollectionurl -OwnerAlias OwnerName  -Name "Name of site collection"
Add-SPUserSolution -LiteralPath Path_To_WSP_Template_File -Site http://newsitecollectionurl
#Wait till above command is finished

Install-SPUserSolution -Identity TemplateWSPName.wsp -Site http://newsitecollectionurl

#Now we need to find the Web Template ID ... You can use below loop to find it out

$site= new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(http://newsitecollectionurl)
$loc= [System.Int32]::Parse(1033)
$templates= $site.GetWebTemplates($loc)
foreach ($child in $templates)
{
    write-host $child.Name "" $child.Title
}
$site.Dispose()

#Now Apply the template

$web = GET-SPWeb $mainurl
$web.ApplyWebTemplate("{<GUID>}#<CUSTOMTEMPLATE>")
```

[How to create root site collection with custom web template using PoweShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133809/how-to-create-root-site-collection-with-custom-web-template-using-poweshell)